# Node JS - Express, Socket.io complete session destruction when user logs out

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

The session variable is created when user logs in to the system. Then I load session variable in my authorization code. I want to destroy that variable when user logs out. Here is some simplified code

```
 store = new express.session.MemoryStore();
 var parseCookie = express.cookieParser('secret');
 app.use(parseCookie);
 app.use(express.session({store: store, key:'sid'}));


    app.post('/login', function(req,res){
       var post = req.body;
       if (post.user == 'hugo' && post.password == '123') 
       {
          req.session.user_name = post.user;
          res.redirect('/mypage');
       } 
       else  res.send('wrong user or pass');
    });


    io.set('authorization', function (data, callback) {

         parseCookie(data, {}, function(prserr) {
            var sess = (data.secureCookies && data.secureCookies['sid']);
            store.load(sess, function(err, session){
               if (err || !session ) { callback('not logged in', false); }
               else { 
                       data.session = session;  // save session
                       callback(null, true); 
                    }
            });     
         });

     });
```

**and finally**

```
     app.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
        req.session.destroy();
        /* Here I want to destroy session variable that is declared in 
           authorization code (see above: data.session = session )*/
        res.redirect('/'); 
     });
```

while destroying  session via  `req.session.destroy()` the variable
`socket.handshake.session.user_name` still exists. I want to destroy it too. But I have no idea how to access desired variable in above mentioned place (in logout code).

Comment: That session is not destroyed until you reconnect from Socket connection. You can disconnect the socket connection from the server.

Answer (score -2):

Have you considered using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)? It might be quicker (and more efficient) than trying to roll your own authentication solution.